# How to delete entered data PHP?

Tags: php

I have a program where I upload a photo and it gets displayed above. There isn't any AJAX so after I refresh the page, the photo shows up. But if I refresh again, the photo is re-uploaded and displayed. How do I get the data to delete after it was initially uploaded?

Here is the main page.

```
   <?php


include 'id2.php';

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file)) {
echo "Please select image.";
} else {
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size==FALSE) {
    echo 'that is not an image.';
    } else {
     if (!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo VALUES ('', '$image_name', '$image')")) {
      echo "Problem uploading image";
     }
    }

}



?>


<form action="Photosite.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My image display page.

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `photo`.`photo`";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
echo '<'.'img src="id.php?id='.$data['id'].'">';
}
```

And the rest

```
$id = abs($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `image` FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE id='$id'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die (mysql_error());
$image = $data['image'];



$jpgimage = imagecreatefromstring($image);




    $image_width = imagesx($jpgimage);
    $image_height = imagesy($jpgimage);

    $new_size = ($image_width + $image_height)/($image_width*($image_height/45));
    $new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
    $new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);


    imagecopyresized($new_image, $jpgimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);

      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($new_image, null);


?>
```

I feel like the answer is simple but I am new at this so thanks!

Oh and yes I know some of my query functions are out-of-date!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is called [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).  It has nothing to do with the "deleting" of data, but you want to make a separate GET request after POST to prevent duplicate submissions of POST data (and to be a bit more user friendly).

After successful form submission and storage in the DB, do:

```
header('Location: /path/to/view/uploaded/image', true, 303);
exit;
```

...or redirect to wherever you want the user to go even if it's the same page.

Comment: @AyeshK although it probably wouldn't matter, technically yes it should be 303.  I updated the answer.  I was trying to do it without looking it up.

Comment: Ok thanks, I know I could have just used redirects but i was wondering if there was another way, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The photo is getting upload again because the form is being submitted again when you refresh the page. To delete a photo you'll need to write a query along the lines of:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM photo WHERE id = " . $id_of_image;
```

If you don't wish the photo to be uploaded on refresh then you should redirect the page after the file gets uploaded.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `header('location: showimagefile.php?imageid');`  on the end of upload file.  Thi sway they can't click ctrl + r to refresh the page and reupload the image. If they go back one page it'll ask them to resubmit data though, use a query to see that no rows with that data already exist.s.